# Como adicionar mais de uma string numa List

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Eu tenho um sistema de cadastro de clientes e estou tentando adicionar produtos aos clientes cadastrados. Para a lista do cadastro eu tenho o seguinte:

```
public class Cliente
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string CPF { get; set; }
    public List<ProdutoComprado> Comprou { get; set; }
}

public class ProdutoComprado
{
    public string NomeProduto { get; set; }
    public string ValorProduto { get; set; }
}

public static List<Cliente> Clientes = new List<Cliente>();
public static List<ProdutoComprado> ProdutosComprados = new List<ProdutoComprado>();
```

Para cadastrar o cliente, eu uso o seguinte código:

```
private void btnCadastrarCliente_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
        cliente.Nome = caixaClienteNome.Text;
        cliente.CPF = caixaClienteCPF.Text;
        listaClientes.Items.Add(cliente.Nome);
        Clientes.Add(cliente);
    }
```

Para cadastrar um produto para o cliente eu uso:

```
private void btnCadastrarProduto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cliente procli = Clientes[listaClientes.SelectedIndex];
        procli.Comprou = new List<ProdutoComprado>
        {
            new ProdutoComprado
            {
                NomeProduto = caixaProdutoComprado.Text,
                ValorProduto = caixaValor.Text
            }
        };
        foreach (var prod in procli.Comprou)
        {
            ProdutosComprados.Add(prod);
            listaProdutosComprados.Items.Add(prod.NomeProduto);
        }
    }
```

Note que o código usa como matriz o cliente selecionado na listbox dos clientes, para que o produto seja adicionado a ele.
Também uso JSON.net para salvar os dados, e tenho como output o seguinte:

```
[
    {
        "Nome": "João",
        "CPF": "00000000000",
        "Comprou": [
                       {
                           "NomeProduto": "Carro 4x4",
                           "ValorProduto": "R$40000"
                       }
                   ]
    }
]
```

O problema é que este código só adiciona 1 produto. Se eu seleciono o cliente e cadastro outro produto para ele, o produto ao invés de ser adicionado simplesmente sobrescreve o anterior.
Ao invés de salvar dessa forma, por exemplo:

```
[
    {
        "Nome": "João",
        "CPF": "00000000000",
        "Comprou": [
                       {
                           "NomeProduto": "Carro 4x4",
                           "ValorProduto": "R$40000",
                           "NomeProduto": "Moto Honda",
                           "ValorProduto": "R$20000"
                       }
                   ]
    }
]
```

..ele salva assim, sobrescrevendo o anterior:

```
[
    {
        "Nome": "João",
        "CPF": "00000000000",
        "Comprou": [
                       {
                           "NomeProduto": "Moto Honda",
                           "ValorProduto": "R$20000"
                       }
                   ]
    }
]
```

Como adicionar um produto seguido do outro?

Comment: Fiquei lendo um bom tempo, tentando interpretar e não consegui entender o que o seu código faz e qual o problema dele. Salvo eu estar me equivocando em algo provavelmente está faltando partes relevantes de código ou uma explicação melhor.

Comment: @bigown Obrigado por seu comentário! Eu não inseri uma outra parte desse código para não haver informações demais, o que atrapalharia na resolução do problema. Esta outra parte consiste em cadastrar o cliente. Atualizei a pergunta e peço que dê uma olhada.

Comment: Realmente o cadastro do cliente parece ser irrelevante. Os JSON ajuda entender um pouco mas não sei em que parte do seu código está lidando com ele. Por exemplo, eu não sei o que é `caixaProdutoComprado.Text`, não o que é `listaProdutosComprados` só p/ citar duas informações que está aí como mágica. na verdade todo o código está difícil identificar o que faz. Mas claramente a parte do código que usa esse `caixaProdutoComprado.Text` está pegando só um produto, seja lá de onde vem isto. O problema basicamente está aí. Você tem que pegar outros, mas só vendo isto não tem como ajudar.

Comment: @bigown caixaProdutoComprado.Text é o texto de uma textbox. listaProdutosComprados é uma listbox onde os produtos do cliente deverão ser adicionados. O nome do produto vem da textbox caixaProdutoComprado no momento que o usuário pressiona o botão de cadastro de produto. O meu problema é que não consigo adicionar mais que um produto. Como eu disse na pergunta, se já houver um produto, ao clicar no botão de cadastro para cadastrar um novo, ao invés dele ser adicionado como exemplifiquei no JSON, ele sobrescreve o anterior.

Comment: @bigown não dá pra especificar todos os produtos de uma vez porque eles devem ser adicionados separadamente.

Answer (score 3):

Como apontado nos comentários, seu código está bem difícil de entender mas algo me chamou atenção como potencial problema:

```
procli.Comprou = new List<ProdutoComprado>
{
    new ProdutoComprado
    {
        NomeProduto = caixaProdutoComprado.Text,
        ValorProduto = caixaValor.Text
     }
};
```

Você está sempre gerando uma nova lista, o ideal seria apenas chamar:

```
procli.Comprou.Add(new ProdutoComprado
{
    NomeProduto = caixaProdutoComprado.Text,
    ValorProduto = caixaValor.Text
});
```

Deste modo você estará sempre adicionando na lista.

Edit:

Como apontado nos comentários desta resposta, você precisa criar a lista antes de chamar o método "Add". O ideal é que você faça isso no construtor da classe de Cliente:

```
public class Cliente
{
    public Cliente()
    {
        Comprou = new List<ProdutoComprado>();
    }

    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string CPF { get; set; }
    public List<ProdutoComprado> Comprou { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Um detalhe: a lista vai ter de ser criada quando a classe Cliente e criada, caso contrario `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Bem observado @Omni. Isso até passou pela minha mente, mas cogitei a hipótese dele estar repetindo o new dentro do construtor da classe Cliente. É o que eu possivelmente faria.

Comment: somos dois a fazer de forma igual. De qualquer forma, julgo que mais vale jogar pelo seguro.